# TEX Studio and Table of Contents not Appearing

Tags: table-of-contents, texstudio, html

I have this following code, and setup

```
% !TEX TS-program = pdflatex
% !TEX encoding = UTF-8 Unicode

% This is a simple template for a LaTeX document using the "article" class.
% See "book", "report", "letter" for other types of document.

\documentclass[11pt]{article} % use larger type; default would be 10pt

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % set input encoding (not needed with XeLaTeX)

%%% Examples of Article customizations
% These packages are optional, depending on whether you want the features they provide.
% See the LaTeX Companion or other references for full information.

%%% PAGE DIMENSIONS
\usepackage{geometry} % to change the page dimensions
\usepackage{setspace}
\geometry{a4paper} % or letterpaper (US) or a5paper or....
\doublespacing
% \geometry{margin=2in} % for example, change the margins to 2 inches all round
% \geometry{landscape} % set up the page for landscape
% read geometry.pdf for detailed page layout information

\usepackage{graphicx} % support the \includegraphics command and options

% \usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent

%%% PACKAGES
\usepackage{booktabs} % for much better looking tables
\usepackage{array} % for better arrays (eg matrices) in maths
\usepackage{paralist} % very flexible & customisable lists (eg. enumerate/itemize, etc.)
\usepackage{verbatim} % adds environment for commenting out blocks of text & for better verbatim
\usepackage{subfig} % make it possible to include more than one captioned figure/table in a single float
\usepackage{amsmath} % allow the usage of math symbols, and tools
\usepackage{hyperref} % allows the usage of hyperlinks for sections in the project
% These packages are all incorporated in the memoir class to one degree or another...

%%% HEADERS & FOOTERS
\usepackage{fancyhdr} % This should be set AFTER setting up the page geometry
\pagestyle{fancy} % options: empty , plain , fancy
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt} % customise the layout...
\lhead{}\chead{}\rhead{}
\lfoot{}\cfoot{\thepage}\rfoot{}

%%% SECTION TITLE APPEARANCE
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily\mdseries\upshape} % (See the fntguide.pdf for font help)
% (This matches ConTeXt defaults)

%%% ToC (table of contents) APPEARANCE
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind} % Put the bibliography in the ToC
\usepackage[titles,subfigure]{tocloft} % Alter the style of the Table of Contents
\renewcommand{\cftsecfont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
\renewcommand{\cftsecpagefont}{\rmfamily\mdseries\upshape}
```

My Question is why with this setup its not processing my table contents when it converts to HTML. I am frankly questioning this because its just that page, ever other page processed fine.

```
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\newpage
\tableofcontents
\newpage
```

Comment: Which utility are you using to convert tex to html? TeXstudio is just an editor hence is not relevant in most cases.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ I just downloaded it and clicked under tools and convert to HTML.

Comment: In the "Convert to Html" window, left-lower area, change value of option "Number of compilations" from 1 to 2. Then click "Launch" and the output html contains the table of contents.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ Post that as an answer cause that worked. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From question comment:

> In the "Convert to Html" window, left-lower area, change value of option "Number of compilations" from 1 to 2. Then click "Launch" and the output html contains the table of contents.

[image]

PS: The "Convert to Html" utility in TeXstudio uses a `tex -> dvi -> ps -> html` chain. Hence you need to set appropriate "Number of compilations" to make sure the intermediate result `dvi` contains the desired contents.